# How to remove a Cesium event listener after use Angular?

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I have a function that adds a Cesium event listener in a subscription.
I would like to know how to remove it after use.

Here is my code :

```js
this.layerService.visibilityChange.subscribe((layer){
    viwer.scene.globe.tileLoadProgressEvent.addEventListener((count) => {
        console.log(count);
        if(viewer.scene.globe.tilesLoaded){
            viewer.imageryLayers.pickImageryLayerFeatures(ray, scene);
        }
    })
})
```

After executing this code, the event is still console.log the count each times tiles are loaded. How can i remove it juste after the `pickImageryLayerFeatures()` has executed ?

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) helps you out?

Comment: If possible, don't add addEventListener inside subscription for performance reasons. instead, do it in any lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Something is wrong but i do not know what.. In fact, I do not use the `'event'` parameter, is it part of the problem ?

Comment: @harpal Ok, i will check that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just like `addEventListener` you can also remove event listner.

```
viwer.scene.globe.tileLoadProgressEvent.removeEventListener(myFunction);
```

Comment: Yes, but as i have no "click" parameter, is there a way to identify listener ?

Comment: @Mateen This question is about [`globe.loadProgressTileEvent`](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Globe.html#tileLoadProgressEvent) which is a [`Cesium.Event`](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Event.html) and doesn't have the same usage as the DOM events you've referenced here.

Comment: @Fab83i I have updated my answer please have a look, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I have read [Cesium doc](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Event.html#addEventListener)  eheh, And Cesium tell us that tileLoadProgressEvent return a function that will remove this event listener when invoked.

Comment: This is correct, it returns a callback to remove the listener.  You could improve this answer by editing out the "read the doc" part and just state the solution along with a link to the [`Cesium.Event`](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Event.html) documentation.